# Get info from logged in person Facebook Graph API

Tags: java, android, facebook

How can I get information about the logged In person via the Graph API?

I have looked at the `GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest`, and that seems straight forward. But how do I get the friends? Taggable friends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get taggable friends by below code

```
if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null)
{
    GraphRequest graphRequest = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "me/taggable_friends",
            new GraphRequest.Callback()
            {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse)
                {
                    //Your code

                    if(graphResponse != null)
                        {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = graphResponse.getJSONObject();
                            String taggableFriendsJson = jsonObject.toString();
                            Gson gson = new Gson();
                            TaggableFriendsWrapper taggableFriendsWrapper= gson.fromJson(taggableFriendsJson, TaggableFriendsWrapper.class);
                            ArrayList<TaggableFriends> invitableFriends = new ArrayList<TaggableFriends>();
                            invitableFriends = taggableFriendsWrapper.getData();
                            int i;
                            for(i = 0; i < invitableFriends.size(); i++)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    MainActivity.myMenu.add(invitableFriends.get(i).getName());
                                }
                                catch(Exception e){}
                            }
                            MainActivity.myMenu.add("Tot: " + i);
                        }else {

                        }
                        //response.get

                }
            }
        );

        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putInt("limit", 5000); //5000 is maximum number of friends you can have on Facebook

        graphRequest.setParameters(parameters);
        graphRequest.executeAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Can I aslo get the user information(name, age etcetc) from the request?

Comment: yes you can take gender and birthdate and from birthdate you need to calculate age.

For gender and birthdate you need to give user_birthday , user_about_me permission.

Comment: And where do I specify the fields In the code? You have set "me/taggable_friends" to get the taggable_friends. But how about the user information such as name and so on?

Comment: For user information you need to use newMeRequest instead of newGraphPathRequest.

Comment: So I can't get the user information In the same request as the taggable_friends?

Comment: refer this link for more info regarding this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user

Comment: That did not help me. I've already read that. The thing I want to do Is to get all the information (user information and taggable friends) In one single request. Can u help me with that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90227/discussion-between-kishudroid-and-bryan).